# What is the schema used to define an Azure Devops (VSTS) Build Definition

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to located the Schema used to define a build or builds in Azure Devops. I have exported a build and would like to use VS Json Outline to view it -- perhaps build out a parser.

I noticed in VS there are references to http://json.schemastore.org/...lots of schemas..., but the site does is not  brow-sable.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it makes sense to go that route, Azure Devops has got the ability to define builds in yaml, schema is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema). you can use those yaml builds to manage builds at scale and reuse definitions or parts of those (depending on how you structure your stuff)

Json stuff is the old way of exporting\importing builds, its not really meant for managing builds at scale

Comment: Unfortunately YAML tooling just isn’t there yet

Comment: certainly better experience than json

Comment: JSON is what is generated as the build definition by the interface. I just want to use the artifact. There must be a schema behind it.

Comment: not exposed publicly, or rather, its probably an export from the rest api

Comment: Any way to get it ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0 this most likely